# TypeScript extending an interface with Array

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger

Not sure if its even possible, but let me ask. I am getting started with Angular 4 and am trying to do implement parent interface.

```
export interface Devices extends Array<Device> {
}
```

Following gives me an error 'Class 'DevicesModel' incorrectly implements interface 'Devices'. Property 'includes' is missing in type DevicesModel'.

```
export class DevicesModel implements Devices {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

I am guessing since its an insance of an array, i am not allowed to add other attributes to the model.

Reason i am doing this is. Devices is generated from swagger document. I wanted to separate swagger models from application models. So I am implementing all swagger generated models so that if I have to modify the models, i don't lose them when i regenerate them. 
If the above is not possible, i guess i have to use composition technique to do that i was trying to do.

Thanks

**EDITs:**

**More Information:**

Here is my swagger YAML looks like that defines rest services.

```
Devices:
  type: array
  description: list of devices
  items:
    $ref: '#/definitions/Device'
Service:
  type: object
  required:
    - serviceId
    - serviceName
  properties:
    serviceId:
      type: string
    deviceName:
      type: string
    serviceName:
      type: string
    port:
      type: string
    tag:
      type: string
```

My swagger generated Rest server model looks like this:

```
@ApiModel(description = "list of devices")
@Validated
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2018-02-23T10:57:40.757-05:00")

public class Devices extends ArrayList<Device> implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
....
}
```

I am generating typescript rest client using swagger codegen and it generates Devices model as:

```
export interface Devices extends Array<Device> {
}
```

I think my safest bet is to change Yaml so that generated objects do not extend Array but use composition. Something like this:

```
public class Devices implements Serializable 
{
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     private List<Device> devices;
     ....
}
```

And Typescript would then be:

```
export interface Devices {
     devices: Array<Device>;
}
```

As I said, I am just starting with Typescript and Angular and being Java coder, i am trying to apply java techniques into TypeScript which is making it a little complicated i guess. Since I am learning, i think I will stick simple solution for now.

Thanks again.

Comment: This *may* be of some help to you: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: What's the question exactly?
You're defining a class, of which you say it implements the array interface. Arrays have an "includes" property, so you need to implement it too.

Comment: Added more information. I think i will change the yaml to make it use composition pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making your interface `Devices` extend `Array<Device>`, it is then expected that any class implementing `Devices` also implements all of the methods of an `Array`, more specifically of an `Array<Device>` here. In the end you're trying to extend an `Array` here, so you'll have do define [all the methods available in an `Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for you class to be considered as one, such as `include` but also a ton of other ones.

While this is the explanation for what's happening, it might not be what you're looking to do. [This article](https://blog.simontest.net/extend-array-with-typescript-965cc1134b3) might be an interesting read about what are the possibilities, besides not trying to extend `Array`.

Keep in mind that in any case, TypeScript ends in JavaScript. As you're not able to extend an `Array` in JavaScript, it'll probably be a bit tricky in TypeScript, or at least less natural that you'd expect it to be.

The article describes multiple ways to get around the problem, with each having different properties. Basically, solutions include :

- Replacing all of the missing properties at runtime (Bad because slower and breaks inheritance)
- Not extending `Array` in the first place but *having* a parameter that is an `Array`.
- Tricking things to behave in a kind of logic way by masking your usual class constructor and having to call it otherwise so that the class is created the way you want.

While the last solution may seem to be the trickiest, it might be the "best" one here as it'll be less prone to errors while using it.

I'm merely pasting here a bit of the last snippet of code from the article to clarify things :

```
class MyArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    private constructor(items?: Array<T>) {
        super(...items)
    }
    static create<T>(): MyArray<T> {
        return Object.create(MyArray.prototype);
    }
}

// Works
const myArray = MyArray.create<string>();
```

Here, we successfully created an instance of the type we wanted without using its classic constructor, but using [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). We then simplified the use of it by making a static method to instantiate our objects.

I hope this answered your problem or question. You didn't specify exactly what you're trying to achieve, so I think it's best for you to decide by yourself if you want to use that solution or not.

Comment: To make this code with `items?` work, I changed the `super` call to: `super(...(items || [])`